# Specified key was too long creating primary key

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Simple question: what is wrong here?
Using `utf8` (*CHARSET=utf8mb4*) makes the internal fields larger.
What is the maximum field size for UTF8 keys?
We need to guess?

```
create table repos(repo varchar (200), PRIMARY KEY (repo));
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

How hard is for `mariadb` to give a better error message?
btw: The answer, by trial and error, is **191** * 4 + 4 = 767.

*<sub>`mariadb` Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.47-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2</sub>*

Answer (score 0):

[767 Limit in InnoDB Indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes) lists 5 work arounds for the 767 problem.

But, these days, the preferred solution is to upgrade:

This problem exists before the limit was raised in 5.7.7 (MariaDB 10.2.2?).